# C++ Class for Boxing & Unboxing

Tags: c++, oop, templates

I want to have a class `Boxed_value` that can `InBox` other types (starting from `int`, `double`, `string`...), similar to `object` in `C#`. This class type can be further passed to functions that `Unbox` it. These functions will receive a reference:

```
void receiver( Boxed_value & bv ) {}
```

So, it shouldn't be a template. Or? I need a recipe... The `UnBox` function can be separate, and templated. In this case `receiver` can get 2 parameters:

```
void receiver( Boxed_value & bv, Engine & eng ) {}
```

The implementation below is dummy and it's not compiling.

```
struct Boxed_value {
    void inbox(int v) { _iv = v; }
    void inbox(double v) { _dv = v; }
    void inbox(std::string & v) { _sv = v; }

    int _iv;
    double _dv;
    std::string _sv;
};

struct Engine {
    template<typename T>
    T unbox(Boxed_value bv) { 
        if (std::is_same<T, typeid(bv._iv).name()>::value) { return _iv };
        if (std::is_same<T, typeid(bv._dv).name()>::value) { return _dv };
        if (std::is_same<T, typeid(bv._sv).name()>::value) { return _sv };
    }
};
```

Comment: It sounds like you're reinventing [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: @frogatto, `std::variant` can store only 1 currently active type. `Boxed_value ` can store up to three (in a given case). It unboxes the "matching' one. It's nice to know C++17 features. And how to be with C++14?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Note that at compile-time, every `if` clause has to be instantiated; that means you're returning different types in function `unbox`.
2. You should compare the type of members in `std::is_same`, but not sth like `typeid(bv._iv).name()`, which is not type but an object with type `const char*`.

You can apply [Constexpr If](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17).

> If the value is `true`, then statement-false is discarded (if present), otherwise, statement-true is discarded.

And use [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) (since C++11) to get type of the members.

e.g.

```
template<typename T>
T unbox(const Boxed_value& bv) { 
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, decltype(bv._iv)>::value) { return bv._iv };
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, decltype(bv._dv)>::value) { return bv._dv };
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, decltype(bv._sv)>::value) { return bv._sv };
}
```

Before C++17, you can apply [full specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

```
template<typename T>
T unbox(const Boxed_value& bv);

template<>
decltype(Boxed_value::_iv) unbox<decltype(Boxed_value::_iv)> (const Boxed_value& bv) { return bv._iv; }
template<>
decltype(Boxed_value::_dv) unbox<decltype(Boxed_value::_dv)> (const Boxed_value& bv) { return bv._dv; }
template<>
decltype(Boxed_value::_sv) unbox<decltype(Boxed_value::_sv)> (const Boxed_value& bv) { return bv._sv; }
```

PS: I changed the parameter type from `Boxed_value` to `const Boxed_value&`, to avoid unnecessary copy.

Comment: @user2376997 Workaround added.